# How to pass a List<Note> in JSF composite component?

Tags: jsf, composite-component, parameterized-types

I have to create a JSF composite component where, I have to pass a attribute like below:

```
<composite:attribute name="noteList" type="XXX" required="true"></composite:attribute>
```

> what should I pass in **type** attribute if it is a List of type Note
>   class?

I know I can make type="java.util.List", but how can I make it specific to List of type Note?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *but how can I make it specific to List of type Note*

Unfortunately, you can't. It's determined during runtime, during which the generic type information is already lost. Technically, this can be workarounded using reflection trickery, but JSF and EL spec guys may have their own reasons for not specifying it.

Your best bet is to replace it by a custom subclass as below:

```
public class Notes extends ArrayList<Note> {}
```

```
<cc:attribute ... type="com.example.model.Notes" />
```

But this may require changes in the model.

Comment: Ok, got your point, you mean to wrap the whole List<Note> inside another class Notes. Am I correct BalusC?

Comment: Nope. Use `new Notes()` instead of `new ArrayList<Note>()`. Wrapping via constructor can also (it will just create another list), but that's not required.

Comment: You should NOT extend ArrayList!